# Vue application is dropping Axios baseURL

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-router, vuex

I'm muddling my way through implementing JWT authentication in a new Vue app and am running into an issue.  I'm working off of the webpack CLI template FWIW.

In my main.js I have the following code after declaring my Vue app:

```
window.axios = axios
window.axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://example.com'
if (localStorage.getItem('token') !== null) {
  window.axios.defaults.headers.common['authorization'] = 'Token ' + 
    localStorage.token
}
Vue.router = router
```

This works fine when I log in, however after I'm redirected post-login (/sign-up) and then navigate to a new page (/sign-up/inventory) I try the following axios call and get a 404 because the baseURL can no longer be found.

```
axios.get('myapi/myreport/mydata/').then(function (response) {
  console.log(response)
})
  .catch(e => {
    console.log(e)
  })
}
```

If I log window.axios.defaults.baseURL just prior to the axios call I get an error ("Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined") so presumably axios isn't even loading?  What should I be checking in order to trouble-shoot this?

Comment: Just for clarity's sake I am importing axios on my inventory.vue component prior to making the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the axios code up up above my app instantiation on main.js and that seems to have fixed it.